# Failed to use AddAccessAllowedAce to append an ACE to an existing ACL

Tags: windows, security, acl

I use following code to get an ACL from SD:

```
...
PACL pDacl = NULL;
BOOL bDaclPresent = TRUE;
BOOL bDaclDefaulted = FALSE;
if(!GetSecurityDescriptorDacl((PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)spSecurityDescriptor.get(),
                                &bDaclPresent,
                                &pDacl,
                                &bDaclDefaulted))
{
    ReportError(TEXT("Failed to call GetSecurityDescriptorDacl."));
    ...
}
```

Then I use AddAccessAllowedAce to append a new ACE:

```
if(!AddAccessAllowedAce(pDacl,
                        ACL_REVISION,
                        MQSEC_QUEUE_GENERIC_ALL,
                        pAnnySid))
{
    dwErrCode = GetLastError();
    ReportError(dwErrCode);
    ReportError(TEXT("Failed to call AddAccessAllowedAce."));
    ...
}
```

I got an error 1344 that "No more memory is available for security information updates."

Then I tried to increase the size of PACL buffer and changed the PACL header information.
But I still got an error 1336 "The access control list (ACL) structure is invalid."

Could anyone give me a working sample code to do this?

MSDN privided an sample of AddAccessAllowedAce here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms707085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
But it's about to create a brand new ACL, not the same case.

I even think to 'GetAce' from old ACL then 'AddAce' to a new ACL, in the end I append my own new ACE.
But looks like 'AddAce' need a parameter 'nAceListLength'; and I don't know how to get this value from ACE.

Any ideas?

Comment: question solved. 
I can use the following way to get the 'nAceListLength'

    ((PACE_HEADER)(pAce))->AceSized

Comment: ATL security help class can avoid errors like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetSecurityDescriptorDacl() just gives you a pointer to the DACL that is already present in the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR buffer.  If you want to add something to it you need to allocate a larger buffer, copy the existing DACL, then add the new ACE.  You need to do something like the following (pseudo-code off the top of my head; may have errors):

```
PACL pOldDacl = GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSecurityDescriptor);
DWORD cbOldSize = GetAclInformation(pOldDacl, ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION);
DWORD cbNewSize = cbOldSize + sizeof(ACE that you want to add);
PACL pNewDacl = alloc(cbNewSize);
InitializeAcl(pNewDacl, cbNewSize);
for each pAce in pOldDacl // GetAce(pOldDacl)
    AddAce(pNewDacl, pAce);
AddAce(pNewDacl, the ACE that you want to add); // or use specialized functions like AddAccessAllowedAce, etc
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSecurityDescriptor, pNewDacl);
```

Microsoft KB has an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20121231022835/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102102).

Comment: Link especially helpful as covers details on things like putting new Ace before inherited Ace.